# Parse Standard Output on Thread

Tags: java, stdout

I want to start a new thread which will process standard output, and check if each line contains the String `Success!`. This is what I have:

```
final Thread ioThread = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.out));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("Success!")) {
                // FOUND LINE!!
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
ioThread.start();
```

The problem is that the `InputStreamReader` constructor expects an `InputStream`, not a `PrintStream`. How can I fix this?

Comment: A PrintStream is for outputting

Comment: Probably there's a better way to find out that something is completed successfully than for a program to try to parse its own stdout. For now though I could only suggest that you replace the out with your own implementation that tries to parse everything that gets written through it, and other than that routes all bytes to the default out stream.

Comment: #1 Is you app a rest api or a desktop app? #2 Do you want to listen all the stdout (System.out.println("hello")) of your app? Usually we need the stdout of another process, not the app itself

Comment: Change System.out to `System.in`.  You cannot read from an OutputStream.